# asynchronous Form w/ Iframe Target -- OnLoad works in FF, Chrome, IE9, doesn't get response in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an ajax-style form in a popup window in my app. I use a form with a target iframe, then on the iframe.load() function, I take the contents and display them back into my popup.

This works on IE9, Chrome, Firefox:

```
 $("iframe[name=addpart-iframe]").load(function () {
            //FF and IE fire the load when the popup first load, chrome does not. This kips the first onload where no submit has happened yet
               if (firstLoad == true) {
                   firstLoad = false;
                   return;
               }


               var response = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
               $("#AddForm").html(response);


           });
```

This works great, except in IE7. When I look at this.contentDocument.body -- the debugger says that body is not a valid property. I look at the outer HTML, and my iframe is also empty at this time. Not sure why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `contentDocument` property refers to the document element inside the iframe (this is equivalent to `contentWindow.document`), but is not supported by Internet Explorer versions before IE8.

For earlier versions of IE before 8, you can use `contentWindow` property.

```
var response;

if (this.contentDocument) {
    response = this.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
} else {
    response = this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This ended up being more problematic than I thought. Turns out my iframe resposne did not have proper <html><head></head><body>..etc. This was fine in chrome, ff, etc as the response was never rendered as a standalone page, but IE barfed and threw everything inside of my iframe's <head> when I did this. Fixed up the doc format of my response and ended up just using $("iframe").find("<myformdivhere>") instead of either. Thanks though!